# How to decide between different robust standard errors?

Tags: least-squares, standard-error, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error, leverage

Specifying my model I ran into some very mild heteroscedasticity problems. Given its superior small-sample properties (my dataset contains 79 observations) I used the HC3 specification of the White heteroscedasticity robust standard errors. However it renders almost all my estimates non-significant. Playing around with the data it showed that the significance levels relied on the type of the robust standard error used (HC0 to HC3) to a large extent. Also I couldn't use HC3 on all my models, apparently because its performance relies on the size of the hat values.

Now I'm slightly confused. How can I decide between these different standard errors? I don't actually have many high leverage points so is HC3 even appropriate?

Some more information on the data:
The sample size is fixed, as I'm working within comparative political science. My dependent variable is a left skewed 0-100 index. Most of the independent variables follow a normal distribution, those that don't were logged. Further a region-dummy is included

```
structure(list(ID = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", 
                            "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belarus", "Benin", "Bolivia", 
                            "Burkina Faso", "Burma/Myanmar", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", 
                            "Central African Republic", "Chad", "China", "Cuba", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
                            "Djibouti", "Egypt", "Eritrea", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", 
                            "Gabon", "Guinea", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iran", "Iraq", 
                            "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", 
                            "Lebanon", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Mauritania", 
                            "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Oman", 
                            "Pakistan", "Papua New Guinea", "Philippines", "Qatar", "Republic of the Congo", 
                            "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Somalia", 
                            "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Syria", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", 
                            "Togo", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
                            "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), 
                     Dep_Var = c(84.26, 89.81, 92.13, 90.74, 96.3, 78.7, 93.52, 
                                 19.44, 70.83, 96.3, 89.81, 86.11, 33.33, 68.52, 71.3, 75.93, 
                                 88.89, 81.94, 100, 80.56, 100, 84.26, 93.52, 89.81, 80.56, 
                                 88.89, 81.48, 78.7, 87.04, 100, 76.85, 64.35, 96.3, 100, 
                                 89.35, 93.52, 100, 92.13, 96.3, 85.19, 95.37, 57.41, 75, 
                                 72.22, 77.78, 93.52, 80.56, 16.67, 61.11, 85.65, 100, 96.3, 
                                 83.8, 100, 86.11, 97.22, 87.04, 90.74, 94.44, 100, 85.19, 
                                 60.19, 86.11, 91.67, 86.11, 73.15, 50, 82.41, 73.15, 77.78, 
                                 58.33, 93.52, 92.59, 89.81, 96.3, 87.04, 96.3, 70.83, 87.96
                     ), Var1 = c(4.127, 5.251, 5.296, 6.541, 6.672, 6.414, 6.78, 
                                 6.062, 7.056, 5.78, 5.786, 4.552, 3.537, 5.527, 5.608, 6.275, 
                                 3.147, 5.291, 6.55, 4.069, 4.996, 4.586, 4.605, 6.525, 5.409, 
                                 6.302, 6.324, 5.558, 3.996, 6.325, 5.951, 4.481, 3.772, 4.786, 
                                 6.746, 5.645, 6.613, 6.603, 6.306, 3.814, 5.482, 6.14, 6.521, 
                                 4.924, 5.121, 5.355, 5.101, 7.214, 6.554, 6.047, 5.636, 7.175, 
                                 4.735, 5.151, 6.116, 4.799, 5.495, 6.855, 6.197, 6.398, 7.468, 
                                 3.565, 3.891, 5.121, 3.319, 6.826, 5.235, 5.737, 5.703, 4.748, 
                                 5.693, 6.474, 5.836, 6.91, 5.616, 5.979, 5.604, 6.875, 6.48
                     ), Var2 = c(7.71, 7.85, 6.22, 6.93, 5.95, 5.98, 7.46, 1.26, 
                                 3.65, 3.42, 5.84, 3.31, 8.72, 7.88, 6.46, 8.05, 8.86, 5.62, 
                                 4.89, 6.42, 7.13, 5.63, 7.67, 2.84, 4.66, 4.57, 5.63, 6.62, 
                                 8.63, 8.64, 5.01, 3.43, 8.81, 5.72, 6.67, 5.12, 7.09, 6.05, 
                                 3.51, 7.46, 6.88, 5.64, 4.48, 5.68, 7.64, 4.56, 5.4, 7.27, 
                                 3.74, 7.67, 5.2, 7.83, 8.17, 7.09, 8.66, 9.11, 4.12, 2.87, 
                                 6.84, 6.36, 1.83, 8.71, 7.95, 6.59, 7.53, 6.92, 3.77, 6.72, 
                                 5.77, 4.83, 8.15, 5.81, 4.23, 4.3, 5.46, 8.92, 1.94, 5.48, 
                                 7.55), Var3 = c(1.51522335168878, 4.15325778828397, 2.94875838540978, 
                                                 1.00628430938346, 25.4230503312376, 8.18998374332489, 1.04538591988069, 
                                                 1.25351605643943, 1.03389499888613, 1.14765788536537, 1.26573001102583, 
                                                 1.07401182190831, 1.02601777187271, 1.03639332007889, 1.62605356699817, 
                                                 1.92725573397033, 1.01254164138481, 1.03505721838858, 3.46173219653658, 
                                                 1.08295832426121, 57.2882616377008, 1.20022298864129, NA, 
                                                 1.43549075453128, 1.01873682901296, 1.44946193787762, 1.64439543970553, 
                                                 1.00783008956213, 1.14205709505493, 1.08208397251952, 2.40225911107622, 
                                                 22.5235306849493, 1.36123323295883, 1.14848994633969, 1.27546825552435, 
                                                 1.15597071197187, 48.3011823156329, 1.24779693041552, 1, 
                                                 2.15232361681418, 1.10011380715122, 1.05904852323133, 1.67293114440204, 
                                                 1, 1.02209604887292, 1.26595913129412, 1.57959491321159, 
                                                 1.04583300104408, 1.00857974540892, 1.16022802219023, 206.447814325508, 
                                                 1.3232281172556, 1.01139457132996, 1.10081706683103, 3.18921374388388, 
                                                 1.0557568170143, 1.23896346376779, 1.03959784429336, 17.1956183236117, 
                                                 1.80633839574657, 10.3099601319805, 1.02590186237628, 1.02711959279389, 
                                                 3.88462180786233, 1.03514910690513, 6.23547964396164, 1.00861987775186, 
                                                 1.87180599797356, 1.19796183444303, 24.2411476428364, NA, 
                                                 1.02032998088937, 1.91697325378271, 5.22699733044137, 2.96243967880312, 
                                                 3.06551946990564, 1.07671406220387, 1.1343707501751, 1.01365610166913
                                 ), Var4 = c(5.02115486913067, 53.5285741103671, 39.4834327892571, 
                                             29.7359115979868, 47.9358701966989, 235.03977126673, 18.5573982408046, 
                                             66.6329529282582, 12.1943267185875, 35.520687621416, 7.748396902346, 
                                             14.0781314341043, 2.61247472515742, 16.4312138876475, 14.9790917560296, 
                                             4.67907440636335, 7.09540310138533, 102.616791283744, 88.2181889125004, 
                                             5.45216212311342, 34.0884625440838, 30.2003134971543, NA, 
                                             38.3702699384472, 8.57501351042922, 62.2004642089247, 76.6736686126914, 
                                             10.6413123736656, 7.5458791774842, 25.7491219067443, 164.757418389402, 
                                             55.2031078932382, 59.5510901036816, 43.3032934593257, 97.3114520688729, 
                                             18.165469164389, 320.319801025988, 13.0939299165512, 25.3489827724281, 
                                             77.8431685692976, 5.2221980923047, 4.11552340423602, 114.148376618668, 
                                             8.90737285506382, 16.7791925268633, 32.0409500313298, 4.91804723063735, 
                                             19.1290374537869, 5.54600968697425, 22.2985869624463, 154.740324753635, 
                                             12.8470204090039, 28.4518018574842, 34.8508421836621, 647.817331974169, 
                                             20.1107239887663, 115.849953826104, 8.01656186978807, 231.397986561214, 
                                             74.0235455862041, 652.332824392302, NA, NA, 4.41505603374484, 
                                             NA, 8.70787589323223, 11.2212181047515, 78.0819291629949, 
                                             6.75542213340634, 90.4249298288882, 69.6663541063077, 7.76768575885308, 
                                             36.5903131229487, 431.033230583165, 17.248411344137, NA, 
                                             27.1527603640721, 12.9134335737364, 14.6398591018054), Var5 = c(2.086, 
                                                                                                             5.23, 4.112, 2.896, 4.8, 5.36, 3.504, 4.398, 3.868, 4.356, 
                                                                                                             3.844, 2.862, 2.16, 3.862, 3.4, 1.56, 1.942, 5.954, 4.51, 
                                                                                                             1.89, 3.202, 3.83, 1.544, 3.68, 3.786, 5.52, 3.376, 3.058, 
                                                                                                             1.182, 3.758, 5.974, 4.14, 2.358, 5.226, 5.044, 4.178, 4.824, 
                                                                                                             3.776, 3.654, 3.72, 2.694, 3.542, 7.15, 2.99, 3.546, 4.582, 
                                                                                                             3.252, 3.396, 3.468, 2.954, 5.374, 3.732, 3.646, 5.1, 6.262, 
                                                                                                             2.566, 4.878, 5.414, 5.646, 5.224, 9.462, 0.618, 0.102, 1.76, 
                                                                                                             1.658, 2.804, 3.488, 5.7, 2.884, 5.012, 2.912, 3.788, 4.17, 
                                                                                                             7.862, 3.906, 1.836, 4.994, 3.882, 2.602), Var6 = c(43.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                 10.8, 7.5, 2.7, 21.5, 7.4, 27.4, 63.1, 1.5, 3.6, 1.1, 20, 
                                                                                                                                                                 1.4, 18.9, 27.7, 1.9, 0.8, 38.3, 32.4, 18.8, 3.2, 5.6, 1.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                 5, 42.2, 8.2, 14.5, 0.7, 1.6, 2.8, 41.4, 32, 5.6, 37.4, 42.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                 20.7, 39.9, 17.2, 21, 37.4, 0.6, 19, 26.6, 0.5, 1.1, 20.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                 18.1, 46.2, 17.1, 2.8, 26.9, 3.4, 22.7, 20.9, 52.6, 3.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                 47.3, 20.1, 56.3, 19.4, 56.6, 1.5, 27.1, 2.7, 7.8, 16.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                 1.4, 48.1, 1.3, 10.7, 22.2, 1.4, 28.2, 32.9, 22.7, 6.4, 24.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                 21, 3.9), Var7 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var8 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Var9 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 0), Var10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Var11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var12 = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      15L, 18L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 43L, 46L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      48L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 62L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 80L, 81L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      88L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      113L, 114L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 127L, 130L, 135L, 136L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      138L, 139L, 141L, 143L, 146L, 150L, 153L, 156L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      164L, 167L, 170L, 171L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 179L, 181L, 182L, 184L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      185L), class = "data.frame")


model <- lm(formula = Dep_var ~ Var1 + Var2 + log(Var3) +
                 Var4 + Var5 + Var6 + Var7 + Var8 +
                 Var9 + Var10 + Var11 + Var12, 
                 data = subset(df, ID !="Nicaragua" & 
                                   ID != "Belarus" & 
                                   ID != "Burundi"), 
                 na.action = na.exclude)


coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, method = "arellano", type = "HC3"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't use HC3 on all my models"? You can probably compute it in all models, but you have doubts about it's validity, right?

Comment: When different procedures give quite different results the possible actions range from choosing the most appropriate procedure to deciding that the data don't allow firm conclusions. I would choose a middle path here: if you're worried about heteroscedasticity the implication may well be that you need a different model. Also, when a model fit is fragile in any sense the implication may be that you need a simpler model. You aren't telling us anything about the data used except that you have 79 observations, which for your purposes may be anywhere from adequate to dangerously small, depending.

Comment: Possible problem areas include working with the data as they come rather than using appropriate transformations or link functions; using too many predictors.

Comment: @philipp.kn_98: "R returned 'INF' for all estimates and standard errors. This happens once two outliers are excluded or treated with an MM estimator" - this looks very strange to me. There's nothing in the definition of HC3 that requires that you have outliers or leverage points. I suspect you got something else wrong there. Your region dummy is a single 0-1 variable that has both enough zeroes and ones?

Comment: @Lewian I checked again and it returns 'NA' for all estimates and other statistics for all variables. There is no all-0 dummy etc.

Comment: How many predictors do you have?

Comment: @NickCox 12, with 6 of them being dummies

Comment: I'd have said nothing wrong with HC3, but I can't comment on that implementation or whether you used it correctly. What I can say is that "almost all estimates non-significant" is no reason at all against using it (maybe that's just the statistical message of the data), and looking for other estimates in case that some are insignificant that you want significant will just invalidate all your tests. Do the prespecified thing unless there are strong reasons that it is wrong, and I don't see such reasons here, despite R apparently not giving you results.

Comment: Maybe there's some collinearity destroying your fits?

Comment: Crudely, 12 predictors for 79 observations seems a real stretch to me.

Comment: If you're using plain regression the fact that the response is bounded could be severely problematic. In particular,  predictions could be of impossible values more than 100. Nonlinear relationships are likely. Something like a logit link could make more sense. More broadly, your dataset is small enough to list here and I can't see why you don't give the syntax for your model-fitting command and show more results than none. Otherwise there is not enough information here to allow more than comments and guesses.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the usefull comment. I provided the data above

Comment: Thanks for showing the data. That format is fine for R people but pretty hard work for people using other software. I note that with missings (NAs) and your exclusion of 3 countries on whatever other grounds, you're down to 70 observations. I fitted a generalised linear model with logit link and binomial family to the dependent variable divided by 100, which at least matches the bounds. With your plain regression model, some predictions are indeed above 100. I'd put most emphasis on using logit link  and choosing a simpler model. Naturally, you need robust SEs for a non-binary outcome.